# getting error "No playable source found" while i load video with jwplayer

Tags: php, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

Right now i am working with jwplayer, when i load my video it is giving me error like "No playable source found", here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/DkwOvSfA.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">Loading the player...</div>
<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer('container');
playerInstance.setup({
    file: 'https://testvideoout.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/Streaming/mp4_Videos_29_1446555606635',
    image: "https://testvideoout.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/Thumb/Thumb_Videos_29_1446555606635_00001.png",
    primary: 'flash',
    advertising: {
          client: 'vast',
          //tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/preroll.xml',
          schedule: {
                    adbreak1: {
                            offset: "pre",
                            tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/preroll.xml'
                    },
                    adbreak2: {
                            offset: 5,
                            tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/preroll.xml',
                            //type: 'nonlinear'
                    },
                    adbreak3: {
                            offset: 20,
                            tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/preroll.xml',
                            //type: 'nonlinear'
                    },
                    adbreak4: {
                            offset: 80,
                            tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/preroll.xml',
                            //type: 'nonlinear'
                    },
                    adbreak5: {
                            offset: "post",
                            tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/preroll.xml'
                    },
            }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can check file and image both are working still it is giving me error, Can anyone please tell me what is issue ? I tried lot to resolve this issue still i doesn't get success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWPlayer has a problem without a file extension so you have to add the `type` variable (in this case I would say it is `type: "mp4"` :

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer('container');
playerInstance.setup({
    file: 'https://testvideoout.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/Streaming/mp4_Videos_29_1446555606635',
    type: "mp4",
    ...
    ...
```